# Changing local directory name to match github repository name change

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a github repository checked out on my personal computer using Github Desktop for Windows. This has made a folder of the form `C:/Some/Path/Github/Repo_Name` which contains the checked out repository. However, the online repository has changed to a new name, `New_Repo_Name`. Within Github Desktop, the name has changed to match, but my folder is still the old `Repo_Name`. How can I change this folder name to match the new repository name? I'm afraid to simply change the folder name as it may break certain links. Is there a formal way to do this or does changing the folder name work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm afraid to simply change the folder name as it may break certain links.

It should not break any link.
For gitHub Desktop, you might have to re-import the folder, but other than that, the link between the local repo (in its new folder) and the associated remote GitHub repo will be unchanged.

Comment: can you please help me to solve `Push failed myjob: failed with error: fatal: repository 'https://abc@bitbucket.org/abc-abc/myapp.git/' not found`  this issue

Comment: @PranavMS does the url `https://bitbucket.org/abc-abc/myapp.git` (without `abc@`) exist? The url is case sensitive, so double-check first its existence.

Comment: i have solved that issue by changing my repository URL in the config file under the git folder to my new  repository URL. now i am able push and from that repository. thanks @VonC